# Where to put the dependency injection framework config file?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've got a solution with several different projects in it, some are pure class libraries and some are web app projects. If I want my default types to be available to all projects, where should I put the config file for the container?

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is to create it in the solution root directory. Then, for each project that needs it, I do :

- right click->Add Existing
- Browse to, and select file
- Click on down arrow and select "Add as link"
- Select the file in the project
- Properties
- Build Action -> Content
- Copy To Output Directory -> Copy if newer

Then, when you initialise your Dependency Inject framework, you can use something like `Server.MapPath("~/bin/filename.config")`.